# What is the best way to self-host the MVC 2 app in my Windows Service app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, service, windows-services

I have say 3 projects: one the MVC2 app, the second is Windows Service and dll library which is used by Service. I can install and uninstall the service to the system but I need the MVC to be "on" when the service is up and "off" when it is down.

Any other things like IIS is way more appropriate but lets say they are unavailable.

Sorry for my english. In other words, I need to host MVC web app inside my C# Windows Service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC just introduced self-hosting with MVC4 because it replaced the WCF Web API. Before this MVC was oriented towards human-readable websites and not web services, so it didn't make sense to have self-hosting til now. Here is the [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api). If you are limited to MVC2 then I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can host MVC iniside a windows service. You'd just be making your life very difficult. If you you want to bypass IIS you would have to write your own webhosting service.